# Dwolla Balance Error 307

Tags: dwolla

I'm using the official Dwolla PHP Library and trying:

```
$balance = $Dwolla->balance();
if(!$balance) { echo "Error: {$Dwolla->getError()} \n"; } else {
echo "Balance: $balance";}
```

as referenced in the Dwolla Developer Documentation, and getting:

```
"Request Failed. Server responded with: 307"
```

I know I have appropriate Oauth permissions, and if that's an HTTP response, then I believe it's a temporary redirect. What am I missing?

Comment: Nice to see a first comment having useful formatting!

Comment: Do you still get this error or was it temporary? If you still get it, what version of dwolla library are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in the PHP library...